# How to add a text to CheckBox from form2 to form 1 (C#)

Tags: c#

So, I've just started learning C# and I have been looking on tutorials in YouTube but in Console Applications.

I have now made my first WFA and I'm trying to create a Calendar where you can add different times with different texts so you stay informed for example a upcoming test.

So far I've come this far: [It's in Swedish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDABj.png)

And I've also connected the "Lägg Till" (Add in English) to another form called laggTill

Connection in codeform -

```
laggTill lgtl = new laggTill ();
lgtl.Show ();
```

Form2 called laggTill looks like:
[Also in Swedish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YGHI.png)

So my question is, how can I by pressing the "Spara" button (Save in English) put the text from the TextBox in laggTill form to the CheckBox in the "Kommande datum:" CheckBox?

Answer (score 0):

- Create public properties in `Form2`, in the example below you can see how to access them.
- you did not asked that, but sometimes you dont want to update `Form1` (for example the user pressed on cancel button) - use the `DialogResult` value of `Form 2` in order to determine if there is a need to update `Form1`, in the example DialogResult is `DialogResult.OK` but it could be also `DialogResult.Cancel`.

user presses "Spara" button on `Form2`:

```
    public string valueToForm1 { get; set; } //public properties to access from form1
    public DateTime value2ToForm1 { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.valueToForm1 = "SomeValue";
        this.value2ToForm1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
```

calling `Form2` **from** `Form1`:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var form = new Form2())
            {
                var result = form.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //values preserved after close
                    string val = form.valueToForm1;            
                    DateTime dateValue = form.value2ToForm1;
                    //for example
                    this.txtValueFromForm2.Text = val;
                    this.dateTimePicker1.Value = dateValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

on another button on `Form2` (lets say cancel button) you can do that piece of code, if there is a case that you dont want to update `Form1`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
```